# Beyond the codes maximum deflection in primary Aluminum beam

Tags: deformation

we had a alum pool enclosure built that has a primary beam carrying the roof trusses across it's length.   the primary beam is a 4x8 bx beam spanning 43'between supports.

the beam has started to show significant deflection with NO LL. In the dry day it deflects 2 1/2"+ and when it rains it almost reaches 3" of deflection. the code in Floria requires the aluminum structures to be designed using the Al design manual. One of my structural engineers indicated the max deflection for primary beams is L/300 but for a 43' span of such a small beam they would likely cap allowable the deflection at 1 to 1 1/2" maximum. Now the question is no one seems to know at what point does a beam condition like this continue to deform and bend out of position or does it just collapse under a perhaps a wind or LL event.

Comment: Why are you asking us rather than your Structural Engineer? I'm not touching PE related structures.

Answer (score 0):

For a $4x8x1/4$ 6061 aluminum rectangular box section:

Weight, $w = 6.9$ plf

Moment of inertia, $Ix = 42.5$ in^4

Section modulus, $Sx = 10.6$ in^3

Modulus of elasticity, $E = 10,000$ ksi

Yield strength, $f_y = 40,000$ psi

Deflection $\Delta = \dfrac{5wL^4}{384EI}$ in

Insert the parameters into the equation, for the unit weight of 6.9 plf, it will yield 1.25" of dead load deflection, which is smaller than you have observed. So we need to figure out the actual weight (assuming uniform) of the beam, and the respective stress.

Let $w_a = \dfrac{384EI\Delta}{5L^4}$ plf,

and let $\Delta = 3"$

$w_a = \dfrac{384*10,000,000*42.5*3}{5*46^4*12^3} = 12.66$ plf, note $12^3$ is the conversion of feet to inch.

Check the actual maximum stress of the beam (assume simply supported at ends):

$M = \dfrac{w_aL^2}{8} = \dfrac{12.66*46^2}{8} = 3348.6$ pbs-ft

Stress, $\delta = \dfrac{M}{S} = \dfrac{3348.6*12}{10.6} = 3790$ psi

The maximum bending stress is within $0.1f_y = 4000$ psi.

The corresponding deflection ratio is $L/184$.

It seems both stress and deflection are kept within allowable at this time. However, do engage a knowledgeable person to go over my calculations and assumptions for your own safety.

**ADD:** Yoy mentioned that the deflection gets more when rains, which indicates there is potentially a pounding problem that shall also be looked into.

Comment: It seems you might be making the Challenger error here, the system has twice the static deflection you'd expect. Is this due to some unmentioned load, weak boundary conditions, a joint in the beam, or what? Until you know that all bets are off. Having said that yes, the stresses seem to be low compared with the likely material properties.

Comment: @GregLocock The dead load alone only produces a negligible amount of deflection in a span ratio of L/440 (1.25"). Compared with the real deflection (3"), add'l load is anticipated, Since it is the primary beam, conceivably there must have secondary load-contributing members, but its layout can only be verified by the OP. The beam is safe for now but should be checked for further loadings, and that's why I call for review by a knowledgeable person.

Comment: the eng works for the contractor-. both are not responding to why this primary beam i is visibly sagging. when there is a minor wind event the structure creaks and make a cranking sound. Aside from the fact that the local code set the max deflection of L/300 . thats the first part the other side os this issue is serviceability which as an owner this obvious deformation looks bad and uncomfortable.  I asked an opinion of this issue.

Comment: L/300 limit is set on live load deflection only, if you are not in a cold region, the structure might have already experienced the live load events - rain and wind load. In your case, the live load deflection is 3" - 2.5" = 0.5" (L/1100). Is this an overhead enclosure for outdoor poor? Does it support glass?